# how to generate a sequence of values with differents formats in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I want to find rows missing from a sequence of values in my table with differents formats.
For an example, [look at this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f0b07fe525700daec584012201b5a94).

I want to find the missing lines via `c_order_id` and `documentno`. the one with '_p' at the end, and the other without '_p', just the numbers.

```
CREATE TABLE documents (
  "order_id" VARCHAR(22),
  "documentno" VARCHAR(20)
);
INSERT INTO documents
  ("order_id", "documentno")
VALUES
  ('100001120', 'PROFS/2021/02050_P'),
  ('100001125' ,'PROFS/2021/02055_p'),
  ('100001127', 'PROFS/2021/02056'),
  ('100001135' ,'PROFS/2021/02060'),
  ('100001139' ,'AGB/2021/02040'),
  ('100001172' ,'AGB/2021/02047')
```

Query used:

```
WITH cte as (
SELECT LEFT("documentno",12) lpart , MIN(RIGHT("documentno",5)) minpart, MaX(RIGHT("documentno",5)) maxpart  FROM documents
groUP BY LEFT("documentno",12))
sELECT lpart || generate_series(minpart::INTEGER, maxpart::INTEGER)  as missing_documentno FROM cte
except
select documentno from documents
ORDER bY missing_documentno;
```

This query generates

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type integer: "055_p"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regexp_replace()` to cleanup the numbers so that you can cast it to an integer value.

```
with cte as (
  select left(documentno,12) lpart, 
         regexp_replace(split_part(documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int as num
  from documents
), minmax as (
  select lpart, min(num) minpart, max(num) maxpart
  from cte
  group by lpart
)
select m.lpart, t.missing_document_no
from minmax m
  cross join generate_series(m.minpart, m.maxpart) as t(missing_document_no)
order by t.missing_document_no
```

I have split up the "cleaning" of the data and the group into two CTEs to make the steps a bit more readable. Given your sample data, this returns:

```
lpart        | missing_document_no
-------------+--------------------
PROFS/2021/0 |                2050
PROFS/2021/0 |                2051
PROFS/2021/0 |                2052
PROFS/2021/0 |                2053
PROFS/2021/0 |                2054
PROFS/2021/0 |                2055
PROFS/2021/0 |                2056
PROFS/2021/0 |                2057
PROFS/2021/0 |                2058
PROFS/2021/0 |                2059
PROFS/2021/0 |                2060
```

To find the missing values, you can extend the final select to:

```
with (
...
), minmax as (
...
)
select lpart||t.doc_no as missing_doc_no
from minmax m
  cross join generate_series(minpart, maxpart) as t(doc_no) 
where not exists (select * 
                  from documents d
                  where regexp_replace(split_part(d.documentno, '/', 3), '[^0-9]', '', 'g')::int = t.doc_no)
```

Comment: i want to get
'PROFS/2021/02051_P',   'PROFS/2021/02052_P',   'PROFS/2021/02053_P',   'PROFS/2021/02054_P',   'PROFS/2021/02057,   'PROFS/2021/02058,   'PROFS/2021/02059

Comment: @FranckWhite: why is it `PROFS/2021/02051_P` and not `PROFS/2021/02051`? - how do you know when to append the `_P` and when not?

Comment: table come like this, those who have _p should be generate with _p, and the others without _p.
example in the table , i have PROFS/2021/02050_P and PROFS/2021/02055_P, and 'PROFS/2021/02056' and 'PROFS/2021/02060'  i want to get the missing documentno «PROFS / 2021 / 02051_P», «PROFS / 2021 / 02052_P», «PROFS / 2021 / 02053_P», «PROFS / 2021 / 02054_P» and «PROFS / 2021/02057,« PROFS / 2021/02058, 'PROFS / 2021/02059»

Comment: how can i return missing rows that lpart < 12
example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0d3a6a647c6ef2a9063c7f3289446998

Comment: @FranckWhite When can lpart be < 12? It's a [string](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=765b63aa81fa66fcfab4180e387cd3b4)! Please ask a new question - pointing back to this one if required.